# proxy_pass rewrite nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, proxypass

```
    location /(0-9)* {

            #rewrite  ^/(0-9)*$  /disp\.cgi?$1 last;
            rewrite  ^(.*)$  /disp\.cgi?$1  break;
            #include proxy.conf;

            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8999;
    }
```

Hi I'm trying to rewrite (0-9)* and pass it to thttpd. But all I get is a 404 error:
If i Enter http://example.com/123
I get URL '/123' was not found on thttpd
Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the following syntax should work

```
location  / {

            rewrite  ^/([0-9]*)$  /disp.cgi?$1  break;
            #include proxy.conf;

            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8999;
    }
```

If / should ne rewritten to another URL add this as well:

```
location = / {

            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8999/;
    }
```